# Elements move on hover because border is added, padding, as suggested elsewhere doesn't seem to work

Tags: html, css, hover, border

When I hover over an area on my testing website, I made it so a border is added. But because that happens, other elements move. I've looked up other posts, and they recommended adding padding, but that doesn't seem to work because it goes over other stuff.

This is where I add the border:

```
#logo:hover {
  border: 2px solid cyan;
}
```

This is what it was added to:

```
#logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    line-height: 12em;
    border-radius: 200px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Does anyone know how to help me? Also about the way I asked my question.

```css
#logo {
    background-color: black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    line-height: 12em;
    border-radius: 200px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#logo:hover {
  border: 2px solid cyan;
}
```

```html
<div id=logo></div>
```

Greetings,
TheWombatGuru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

box-sizing: border-box doesn't really make the 'circle' render correctly with the border in this case - although it is an amazing property. If it were me, I'd change your css to the following:

```
#logo:hover {
border-left: 3px solid cyan;
border-right: 3px solid cyan;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 6px 0 6px;
}
```

and adjust your #logo class margins to

```
{margin: 0 9px 0 9px;}
```

a little 'hackier', but I prefer the behaviour

Answer (score 3):

You also can use box shadow:

```
 #logo{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px cyan;
 }

 #logo:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px cyan;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may add:

```
* {  box-sizing: border-box;}
```

to your css sheet or maybe just to your `#logo` id.

you may find more info about this (for me at least amazing propertie ) **[here](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)**

(and just in case... the code marked applied the property to every html element in your web, which is exactly what I have been doing in my last many projects with absolutely no regret)

Comment: I agree with your answer, but IMO this CSS property should be set only on `#logo:hover`

Comment: This does stop the elements from moving but it also defeats the purpose of the border in this situation, I added the border so it would line up correctly, but this property seems to add the border to the inside.

Answer (score 2):

You should try adding this to your #logo :

```
border: 2px solid transparent;
```

which would make :

```
#logo {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
top: 80px;
line-height: 12em;
border-radius: 200px;
margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
overflow: hidden;
border : 2px solid transparent;
}
```

Or using `box-sizing: border-box`

Hopes it helps !

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

You should add `box-sizing: border-box` to the pertinent element in your CSS. This will put the padding *inside* the width of the container.

Here is a codepen to demonstrate: http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/LVPPvg

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to `box-sizing: border-box;` you could also use the calc function to subtract a value.

```
#logo:hover {
    width: calc(200px - 4px);
    height: calc(200px - 4px);
    border: 2px solid cyan;
}
```

This method might be helpful when you are dealing with percentages, anyway it's a cool trick i situations like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding border:1px solid transparent; to non hover element.

Answer (score 0):

Try using position: absolute; because elements with position absolute have no effect on other elements. Make sure that the parent element has a position relative. For example

`
#parent-element {
position:relative;

}

#logo {
position:absolute;
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you add this line to `#logo`, elements will not move when hovering.

```
#logo {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

When we apply a border to a borderless element while hovering, the size of the element will increase. We can add invisible border to prevent that unwanted move.

What about adjacent elements? If we add transparent border to adjacent elements, there will be gap between the elements. In this case we should add border with the same color as the background color.

Original Code:

```
#logo {
    background-color: black; /* Background */
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    line-height: 12em;
    border-radius: 200px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Add this line:

```
 #logo {
        border: 2px solid black;
    }
```